# What to do when user edits and breaks the url?

Tags: php

I have a url structure that looks something like some_page.php?id=123 and I get the id for that page and that is good.

But sometimes users either edit the url, or one way or another there is no id.

What do people usually do in that case? Should I just redirect the person to a 404 page? Or should I return 404 from that page in case they want to correct the url? Or is 404 the right thing to do in that case?

Also, how do I tell where this user came from?

Thanks!!

Comment: Because the url doesn't exist I would say that throwing a 404 would be the right thing to do.

Comment: You can check environment variable $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to see where the user came from. Note that it's not reliable, since it depends on the browser sending it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

404, and don't redirect. Show them a nice error page but always give them at least the chance to correct the URL.

Also, make sure to actually send the `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');`

Answer (score 1):

The symfony framework provides some [built-in methods](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_forward404) for dealing with the exact scenario you are describing. So issuing a 404 is a good strategy. Another idea is to offer a suggestive search if the asset cannot be found. For example, instead of just rendering a 404, you could actually do something like:

Sorry we could not find the asset you were looking for, below are some suggestions to better guide your search:

Books (12)

CDs (13)

DVDs (37)

---

This way you increase the users time on site, which should translate to more advertising dollars.